# Changing the background image with Django template tags

Tags: html, css, django

**Solved it: I forgot to escape the quotes.**

I am trying to change a div's background image using Django tags, but I am having problems:

```
 <div class="inner" style="background-image: url("{{ dogs.0.id }}.jpg");">
```

The tag that displays the dog's ID correctly because I use it elsewhere and it displays the right information. Am I using style correctly?

Edit: For some reason, it removes all of the slashes from my URL. So https://www.something.com/dog.jpg becomes https: www.something.com dog.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but offcourse the image needs to exist in the current path you are in since you are using relative url's. Plus you need to set a width and a height for the . Use firebug or Chrome inspector to see if it works and polish up your HTML/CSS knowledge ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: For some reason, it removes all of the slashes from my URL. So 
>   https://www.something.com/dog.jpg becomes https: www.something.com dog.jpg

you can use "safe" filter to avoid this if your dogs.0.id is https://www.something.com/dog

code like this:

```
<div class="inner" style="background-image: url("{{ dog.0.id | safe }}.jpg");">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to dispaly background image in your template in style you need to use following code for inline-css.

```
<div class="inner" style="background-image: url({% static "image-path/background.jpg" %}");>
```